# cron processing only half of script

Tags: scripts, cron, curl

script:

```
curl -s http://api.ipify.org > ~/ip.txt && [[ -s ~/ip.txt ]] && ip=$(cat ip.txt) && echo $ip > ~/newIP.txt || echo WAN IP is blank: curl, latency  or internet issue
# logger -s WAN IP is blank: curl, latency  or internet issue
```

script run only up to:

```
curl -s http://api.ipify.org > ~/ip.txt && [[ -s ~/ip.txt ]] && ip=$(cat ip.txt)
```

the other part is ignored, BUT when I manually sh the script from terminal it execute properly.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a matter of taste, but I personally consider 
those `u > v && w && x > y || z` one-liners unreadable
and especially un-debugable. If they work, they are fine,
but else they are a PITA to my mind.

In your case the mistake was the `ip=$(cat ip.txt)` part
because cronjobs may or may not have the current working
directory set to $HOME. The preceeding `… > ~/ip.txt`
writes a file to your $HOME but the following `cat ip.txt`
tries to access the file `ip.txt` from wherever directory
`cat` was started in. The simple fix woul be to replace
`cat ip.txt` with `cat ~/ip.txt`.

Having said that, I suggest the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ip=$(curl -s -f http://api.ipify.org); then
    echo "$ip" > ~/newIP.txt
else
    echo "WAN IP is blank: curl, latency  or internet issue"
fi
```

This relies on `curl` returning a bad exit value (!=0) if it 
cannot access the give site. If that is not the case, change the
the code to:

```
ip=$(curl -s -f http://api.ipify.org);
if [ "$ip" ]; then
    …
```